# How would I delete records after a certain time based on the value of a specific field?

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime, records

I've got a table called *users*.  Two of the fields in that table are "*activation*" and "*regdate*".  Both are VARCHAR.  The *activation* field contains the string "active" if the user has activated the account.  If the user has not activated the account, the field contains a string which is a randomized alphanumerical activation key.  The *regdate* field contains the date and time that the user registered the account, populated by `date("m.d.y H:m:s")`;.

What I need to do is create a PHP script which will delete all records that do NOT equal "active" in the activation field and are older than an amount of time that I specify.  I know how to locate records by matching criteria such as selecting records where activation equals "active", but I would need it to do the opposite.  I would need it to match all records where activation does not equal "active" (because the randomized string would be impossible to match, would it not?).

Of course, I would then have to also compare the selected records to the current time based on those records' "regdate" field.

So, in short, I've got a bunch of records and I want to delete all of the ones that are older than a certain amount of time and have a field that does NOT equal "active".

I apologize if I did not explain this well enough.  I'm really tired, and this is also my first post on stackoverflow.

Comment: Why isn't the regdate field stored as a `datetime` field in your DB? That will make querying it much simpler.

Comment: are you wanting to run this as a cron job?

Comment: Oh yes, I will be running it as a cron job.  I forgot to mention that.  What would be your recommended interval for the job to run?  Do you think hourly would be appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert your `regdate`field into a `DATETIME` type, the query can be as simple as:

`DELETE FROM users WHERE activation <> 'active' AND regdate < '2011-01-01'`

Otherwise, depending on the format of your regdate VARCHAR,you'llhave to `CAST` or `CONVERT` it to a `DATETIME`before comparing it in your `WHERE` clause.

Is this enough infoforyou togetthisworking?

Comment: That '<>' you showed me in that code snippet was exactly what I needed.  I wasn't sure how to check an inequality in a MySQL query.  I suppose changing the field to a 'DATETIME' type would be the most appropriate.  I hope it will store it as 'mm.dd.yyyy' instead of with year first, though.  Anyway, I will try this.  Thank you.

Comment: @Ronnie: Don't worry how the database itself stores `DATETIME`, it's kind of irrelevant, because as long as it understands it's a date, you can format it any way you want via the `DATE_FORMAT()` function (in MySQL). Most DB engines will default date display and input as `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` because it's universally recognised.

Answer (score 0):

Change your field in the database to "datetime" using mysqladmin should be a breeze ( the data would look something like this "2011-09-13 02:08:20") then you could use standard mysql commands like:

```
mysql_query("DELETE   FROM `iplog` WHERE  DATE(datefield)  <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY) AND activation <> 'active'");
```

this is deleting anything older than 2 days in my 'iplog' table and not active.